# Userform to delete specific records from table always duplicates the last record after deleting a specific record

Tags: vba, excel

I am a little in over my head with this. I am currently working on a User Form that gives the ability to Add, Update and Delete records from a table.

I am having issues with the delete function. While it deletes the selected record, it duplicates the last record from the Table so that the number of records stays the same.

Here is the specific code, c_01 refers to the combobox that contains the unique identifier for each entry.

Delete function:

```
Private Sub B_02_Click()    '   Delete
With c_01
   .RemoveItem .ListIndex
   If .ListCount > 0 Then .ListIndex = 0

   If .ListIndex = -1 Then
     For j = 0 To UBound(.List, 2)
        Me("T_" & Format(j, "00")) = ""
        Me("T_" & Format(j, "00")).Locked = True
     Next
    .Value = ""
   End If
End With
End Sub
```

Save function:

```
 Private Sub b_03_Click()    '   Save
    With Sheets("Data").ListObjects(1)
    .ShowTotals = False
    If c_01.ListCount = 0 Then .DataBodyRange.ClearContents
    If c_01.ListCount > 0 Then .DataBodyRange.Resize(c_01.ListCount).Value = c_01.List
    .ShowTotals = True
End With

Hide
End Sub
```

Any hints as to why this is creating a duplicate of the last record instead of simply just deleting the specified record would be helpful.

If you need the full code or a screenshot of the Userform, I can provide that.

Comment: Can you explain `Me("T_" & Format(j, "00"))`? What is `Me` here? This line should throw an error in my opinion.

Comment: If `Me` is a UDF then put it here.

Comment: @harun24hr I hope `Me` is no UDF because it is a reserved keyword in VBA and should never be used as a UDF name!

Comment: @ harun24hr Me in this case just refers to that Userform. T_01, T_02 and so on are what I named the textboxes of my Userform.

Comment: @Tim I never saw that syntax with `Me(…)` before but obviously that works, so I apologize ;) Can you figure out which line duplicates the records? Debug your code, go through it step-by-step (using F8) and after which step it gets duplicated. Or throw out the lines of code not necessarily needed to illustrate the duplication behavior (build a [mcve]).

Comment: @Tim, added a possible solution by resizing not only the target range, but also the listbox range. - BTW where did you learn the syntax with `Me("T_" & Format(j, "00"))=""` instead of e.g. `Me.Controls("T_" & Format(j, "00")).Text = ""` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No duplicate behaviour - just clear all lines**

You have not only to [0] write the combobox data to the redefined range, you'll have to [1] resize the listobject range, too and [2] clear following lines; otherwise the old data only gets overwritten in parts.

**Example code**

```
 Private Sub B_03_Click()    '   Save
    With Sheets("Data").ListObjects(1)
       .ShowTotals = False
       If C_01.ListCount = 0 Then .DataBodyRange.ClearContents
       If C_01.ListCount > 0 Then
        ' [0] Write combobox values
         .DataBodyRange.Resize(C_01.ListCount).Value = C_01.List
        ' [1] Resize listobject range
         .Resize .Range.Resize(C_01.ListCount + 1)       ' << resize listobject including header (+1), too
        ' [2] Suggestion to clear at least some lines below as well
         .Range.Offset(.Range.Rows.Count).ClearContents  ' << clear lines after listobject table
       End If
      .ShowTotals = True
    End With

    Hide
  End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that suggestion. I already implemented it and it works exactly as intended. And I even learned something in the process. You are a true hero. Thanks again!